# Getting app to start when launching Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I added a shortcut to an app in the windows startup folder. When I create an Amazon EC2 instance (using my own AMI derived from win server 2008 64bit) and connect to it using Remote Desktop from the AWS console, it works fine: once Windows is loaded in the remote desktop, my app starts as expected.

However, if I do not connect to the EC2 instance with Remote Desktop, my app does not start. I can tell because when started, the app sends messages to a queue that I can check from my desktop computer.

My understanding was that the EC2 instance is supposed to be running regardless of whether or not I connect to it using Remote Desktop. Is this not the case? Am I misunderstanding something here?  Ideally, I want to be able to launch multiple instances and have them run an app at startup that carries out some computations without having to manually and individually connect to each instance using Remote Desktop in order to start that specific app. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: it turns out that I needed to add the task to the Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2008 and set the trigger to start app when OS starts and not wait for user log on.